# Zurb Foundation 3 Five Columns

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am testing foundation 3 framework and was wondering how i can set a row with five articles.

Does anyone have an idea to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use columns of two and mark the last column as the end.

> If your row doesn't have a count that adds up to 12 columns, you can
>   tag the last column with `class="end"` in order to override that
>   behaviour. [[source]](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="two columns">
    article 1
  </div>
  <div class="two columns">
    article 2
  </div>
  <div class="two columns">
    article 3
  </div>
  <div class="two columns">
    article 4
  </div>
  <div class="two columns end">
    article 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively if you need to use all the space you can use a [block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php#block-grids):

> Block grids are made from a `ul.block-grid` with `#-up` styles chained to
>   it. You control how many you have in your Scss setting file or the
>   customizer. These are ideal for blocked-in content generated by an
>   application, as they do not require rows or even numbers of elements
>   to display correctly.

```
<ul class="block-grid five-up">
  <li>article 1</li>
  <li>article 2</li>
  <li>article 3</li>
  <li>article 4</li>
  <li>article 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But they don't fill the width. Need five blocks with exactly same size und use available content.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Foundation 5 (maybe 3 as well). The trick is to offset the first column and end the last.

```
<nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column small-2 small-offset-1">
            <a>Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column small-2">
            <a>Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column small-2">
            <a>Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column small-2">
            <a>Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column small-2 end">
            <a>Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps someone, or a future me.